# How to search inside HDFS files

Tags: hadoop, grep, hdfs

I want to be able to search for a pattern of string inside all the folders and files in specific directory in HDFS. not sure how to do it. below does not work.

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /folder_path/ |grep -i "pattern"
```

How do i search?.

Comment: Not sure what you want. You want to search for files which match a specific pattern or you want to search for files which the content match specific pattern?

Comment: I want to search with in the files that are present in a folder for a specific pattern/String

Comment: You need to index the files into Solr/Elasticsearch/Splunk in order to do this effectively. Otherwise you must download the entire files, open them, and then read them.

Comment: what. i cant grep the log files in HDFS? do i really need to copy them to local file system and grep them?

Comment: Yes... Whole Files don't exist in HDFS. They are split apart into individual blocks, which need to be combined to search the content... Even MapReduce has to scan block boundaries to find a word that crosses two blocks

Comment: Alternatively, you would place a Hive table over the logs and use SQL, or use Spark or Pig scripts to search for strings

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For files within a single HDFS folder, you could use the `hadoop fs -cat` command. This will not search within sub-folders though.

To illustrate, if files are in a HDFS folder called `/hive-data`, the following command can be used to search within the files in the directory for a pattern:

```
hadoop fs -cat /hive-data/* | grep -i pattern
```

Comment: How to search through sub-folders though?